# Navigating through a multi layered react app

Tags: reactjs, architecture, components, layer, multipage

I am currently building a react app that has a multi layered component structure where users navigate down into deeper layers. The user would start at the top parent level and then navigate down into deeper and deeper layers of the app (and can also go back up into each previous layer). The layers follow a linear structure (e.g. 1,2,3,4) so there is always a predefined route that users follow, and users could navigate back and forth with a 'next' and 'previous' button. The structure would look like this:

Parent level --> sub level 1 --> sub level 2 --> sub level 3

So each subsequent layer is beneath the previous one. The app itself will render content that gets more detailed and fine grained in each subsequent layer.

My question is how best to represent this structure via components. One option would be to keep track of the current layer via a 'layer' state, and then to show the component that corresponds to the current layer state (as shown in the example code below).

I am unsure whether this is the optimal solution for the structure of my app. I would be very grateful for any suggestions.

Thank you.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
const [layer, setLayer] = useState(1);

const nextLayer = () => {
    setLayer(layer + 1);
}

const prevLayer = () => {
    if (layer === 1) {
            return;
        }
    setLayer(layer - 1);
}

let currentLayerView;
    switch (layer) {
        case 1:
            currentLayerView= (
                <Layer1 
                    nextLayer={nextLayer}
                    prevLayer={prevLayer} 
                />
            );
            break;
        case 2:
            currentLayerView= (
                <Layer2 
                    nextLayer={nextLayer}
                    prevLayer={prevLayer} 
                />
            );
            break;
        case 3:
            currentLayerView= (
                <Layer3 
                    nextLayer={nextLayer}
                    prevLayer={prevLayer} 
                />
            );
            break;
         default:
            console.log('default');
    }

return (
        <>
            {currentLayerView}
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: What you did is fine as long the user can switch from say layer1 to any other layer otherwise it's unneeded complexity. With linear, predefined order, it's simpler to make layer1 a parent, layer2 it's child, etc. If you go with first one, make a global state with navigation stack(array). Push in component's name as you go deeper, pop as you go back, switch components from root component based on it's (array) last value.

Comment: Also ideally you don't push names but objects with name and other data, like scroll position before transition to other screen. When you go back, you ll need it